# visual studio 2010 F10/F11 doesn't break on class member initialization code

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# project in Visual Studio 2010. To understand its logic I use F10/F11 to step through it. Firstly I set a breakpoint at the first line of code in Main(). I expect it to break on every line of code it executes. But actually it doesn't break on the class initialization function and class member fields initialization code. I mean not only the class that the Main() function resides in, but also every other class. For example, the first line of code in Main() is

```
IApplicationContext ctx=ContextRegistry.GetContext();
```

when I press F11 on this line of code, it will jump to the first line of code in GetContext(). But before that, the class member initialization codes and static class initialization code of ContextRegistry should execute firstly. So I need to manually set breakpoint at those places to see clearly what the program actually does. It is quite inconvenient as I need to set breakpoints at every such class.

Is this a configuration problem? I wish I expressed clearly and sorry for my poor English. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have look have a look at the properties of a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The ones  that I believe are relevant to your question are as shown below

- A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.
- A static constructor cannot be called directly.
- The user has no control on when the static constructor is executed in the program.

This is probably why you have to manually set the break-point in the constructor.